# How to use an Overlay without the Navigator/App?

Tags: flutter

Are there any code examples out there that show how to use an Overlay independant of a Navigator widget?

In our app, we do not want the TitleBar/AppBar to be part of the main nav-stack, it should stay at the top of the window, and be fixed position.

The TitleBar needs acccess to an Overlay though, as it has various tool-tips and pop-up panels.

The only I know to do this is double-wrap Navigator, or MaterialApp, both of which smell bad. I would like to use Overlay directly, but lack any guidance on how to implement it.

Looking a the source of Overlay does not provide much help, and I'd prefer not to delve too deeply into MaterialApp's thousands of lines of src code.

[EDIT] Looking at the Navigator source a bit, it seems Overlay is directly coupled to PageRoutes, which is a real shame :'(  It would be nice if there was a simple `Overlay(child: )` we could just use.

Comment: This should be in official Flutter documentation. But instead they just recommend to use MaterialApp or WidgetApp. I came to this question looking for a way to see where this Overlay widget is on screen. Because if I can't see it then I would like to add it to the visual tree myself so I can control its properties and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Overlay` widget that flutter provides,

```
Overlay(
      initialEntries: [
        OverlayEntry(builder: (context) => const RootWidget()),
      ],)
```

Now you will be able to do `Overlay.of()` and insert overlay,
Thanks for checking!

Answer (score -2):

There is declarative package for using overlays called [flutter_portal](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal) which lets you show overlays as part of the widget tree.

```
PortalEntry(
  visible: true,
  portal: Material(
    elevation: 8,
    child: IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ListTile(title: Text('option 1')),
          ListTile(title: Text('option 2')),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: RaisedButton(...),
)
```

With this setup, you can toggle the overlay on and off with a single boolean ('visible') and you no longer have to make calls to Overlay.insert and Overlay.remove.